# How do I get text on to my background img

Tags: css

How do I add all the texts and buttons to display on the background img not below it?
Using Bootstrap 5.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row landingPageBack img-responsive">
    <img src="img/Landing.jpg" alt="">
     <div class="text-center">
        <h1>WELCOME</h1>
        <h2>write me a msg</h2>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg text-center">CONTACT ME</a>  
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CUSTOM CSS

```
/* BG IMAGE*/
body html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.landingPageBack {
    background-image: url('img/Landing.jpg');
    min-height : 100%;
    min-width : 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
/* BG IMAGE*/
.landingPageBack {
    background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1637593755675-c38c18661a86?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1935&q=80');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="landingPageBack">
  <div class="vh-100 vw-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
     <div class="text-center text-white">
        <h1>WELCOME</h1>
        <h2>write me a msg</h2>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mt-3">CONTACT ME</a>  
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Please check the code, Hope it will help you.

Here are some links you should go through:

1. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/
2. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-viewport

Comment: Please edit this with an explanation of how your code works so they can improve later, instead of just copying and pasting your code.

Answer (score 0):

Make the wrapped container div position: relative. Then you can place the image inside and a text Block element. The text-blockelöement must be position: absolute. With the css attribute top and left, bottom, right you can position the text on the image.

```css
/* Container holding the image and the text */
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500/green" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="centered">Centered</div>
</div>
```

And for your example, you would only have to adjust your two classes a bit.

```css
/* BG IMAGE*/
body html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.landingPageBack {
  position: relative; 
}
.text-center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%
}
.landingPageBack {
    background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/500/green');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row landingPageBack img-responsive">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500/green" alt="">
     <div class="text-center">
        <h1>WELCOME</h1>
        <h2>write me a msg</h2>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg text-center">CONTACT ME</a>  
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```